# org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0

Tags: java, json, android-asynctask

I have been stuck on this for a while. Simply cannot figure out whats wrong. A pair of fresh eyes would be very helpful. I keep on getting the org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of and cannot figure it out.

My JSONParser

```
 public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            //HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            //is = httpEntity.getContent();
           JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);
           JSONObject js = jsArray.getJSONObject(0);
           String returnvalmsg = js.getString("message");
           String returnvalsucc = js.getString("success");

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   // } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;


        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

  }
}
```

Activity

```
btnRegisterfine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                             @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // creating new product in background thread
                                new CreateNewFine().execute();
                            }


                      });
    }

                      /**
                         * Background Async Task to Register Fine
                         * */
                        class CreateNewFine extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                            /**
                             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
                             * */
                            @Override
                            protected void onPreExecute() {
                                super.onPreExecute();
                                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Finecalc.this);
                                pDialog.setMessage("Registering Fine..");
                                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                                pDialog.show();
                            }

                            /**
                             * Registering Fine
                             * */
                            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                                String driver = inputDriver.getText().toString();
                                String licencenum = inputLicence.getText().toString();
                                String officer = inputOfficer.getText().toString();
                                String speed = inputSpeed.getText().toString();
                                String fine= FineAppl.getText().toString();
                                String category = inputCategory.getText().toString();


                                // Building Parameters
                                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("driver", driver));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("licencenum", licencenum));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("officer", officer));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("speed", speed));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fine", fine));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", category));

                                // getting JSON Object
                                // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_fine,
                                        "POST", params);

                                // check log cat fro response
                                Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                                // check for success tag
                                try {
                                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                                    if (success == 1) {
                                        // successfully Registered Fine
                                        //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Finecalc.class);
                                        //startActivity(i);
                                        registerFine.setText("DONE");
                                        // closing this screen
                                        finish();
                                    } else {
                                        // failed to Register Fine
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                return null;
                            }

                            /**
                             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                             * **/
                            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                                // dismiss the dialog once done
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                            }

                        }
```

My Php

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['driver'], $_POST['licencenum'], $_POST['officer'], $_POST['speed'] , $_POST['fine'],$_POST['category'])){

    $driver = $_POST['driver'];
 $licencenum = $_POST['licencenum'];
 $officer = $_POST['officer'];
    $speed = $_POST['speed'];
    $fine = $_POST['fine'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];


    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fineregister(driver,licencenum,officer,speed,fine,category) VALUES   ('$driver','$licencenum','$officer','$speed','$fine',      '$category')");

    // check if row inserted or not
 if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Speed Ticket Successfully Registered.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
 }
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

And my error:

> 08-05 09:53:03.321: W/System.err(3072): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
>   08-05 09:53:03.321: W/System.err(3072):     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
>   08-05 09:53:03.321: W/System.err(3072):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
>   08-05 09:53:03.331: W/System.err(3072):     at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:92)
>   08-05 09:53:03.331: W/System.err(3072):     at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:108)
>   08-05 09:53:03.331: W/System.err(3072):     at com.lta.fine.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:60)
>   08-05 09:53:03.341: W/System.err(3072):     at com.lta.fine.MainActivity$CreateNewFine.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:191)
>   08-05 09:53:03.341: W/System.err(3072):     at com.lta.fine.MainActivity$CreateNewFine.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   08-05 09:53:03.351: W/System.err(3072):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   08-05 09:53:03.351: W/System.err(3072):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   08-05 09:53:03.361: W/System.err(3072):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   08-05 09:53:03.361: W/System.err(3072):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   08-05 09:53:03.361: W/System.err(3072):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   08-05 09:53:03.361: W/System.err(3072):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>   08-05 09:53:03.361: E/Buffer Error(3072): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
>   08-05 09:53:03.371: E/JSON Parser(3072): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: Please format your post/code.

Comment: Also add your json data maybe it is just wrong or with an encode that your server cant read

Comment: How do I get json data??

Comment: Did you read the error message??  Your input is zero length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0

Usually means you are not getting any JSON. you will need to debug your app to find out why.

In the mean time I will give you some pointers:

**PHP**

- Not sure if the INSERT is successful  but I noticed you are not using `$db` variable.
- You are open to sql injection using deprecated mysql extension
- you should use boolean in your json
- echo the json at the end.

---

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['driver'], $_POST['licencenum'], $_POST['officer'], $_POST['speed'] , $_POST['fine'],$_POST['category'])){

    $driver = $_POST['driver'];
    $licencenum = $_POST['licencenum'];
    $officer = $_POST['officer'];
    $speed = $_POST['speed'];
    $fine = $_POST['fine'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];


    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fineregister(driver,licencenum,officer,speed,fine,category) VALUES   ('$driver','$licencenum','$officer','$speed','$fine','$category')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Speed Ticket Successfully Registered.";
        // echoing JSON response
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = false;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
}
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

**Java:**

- I see that your method returns a `JSONObject` that limits you already
  from parsing arrays. Instead return the json as string then parse it.
- You are parsing the data inside of the method, this makes it more
  difficult to use.
- I see little to no reason to use `GET` you might as well split that
  function.

---

```
public String makeHttpRequest(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) 
{
    InputStream is = null;
    String json = "";

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }


    // return JSON String
    return json;

}
```

**AsyncTask**

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    String driver = inputDriver.getText().toString();
    String licencenum = inputLicence.getText().toString();
    String officer = inputOfficer.getText().toString();
    String speed = inputSpeed.getText().toString();
    String fine= FineAppl.getText().toString();
    String category = inputCategory.getText().toString();


    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("driver", driver));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("licencenum", licencenum));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("officer", officer));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("speed", speed));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fine", fine));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", category));

    // getting JSON String
    // Note that create product url accepts POST method
    String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_fine, params);

    return json;
}



protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    pDialog.dismiss();
    Log.d("mylog", "json = " + json);
    //parse here
}
```

In `doInbackground` perform the request and pass the result to post execute, log the json object there, if you get anything in the log you can start parsing. using boolean value it will be easier.

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(json);
    Boolean success = jsonData.getBoolean("success");
    String message = jsonData.getString("message");

    if (success) {
    //success
    } else {
    // failed to Register Fine
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: oh and dont forget to check for internet permission!

Comment: Also checked. Permissions is there

Comment: @upasna21 ok?? I was hoping you give me more feedback?

Comment: Hi Meda, sorry for earlier, i slept at 3 then work up at 5 again. Finally sortd out through all you have mentioned. But unfortunately i still get errors. Wish you were around here to help me out. I need this done today one way or theother. so stressed
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
08-05 14:12:56.280: W/System.err(1965):  at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
08-05 14:12:56.290: W/System.err(1965):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)

Comment: Thanks so much meda. Would have never figured out to make changes to php script. really appreciate :)

Comment: @upasna21 Welcome, why did you unaccept the answer `:S`

Comment: Soo sorry. Must hv accidently clicked on my phone...apologies

Answer (score 0):

Your `is` (member var?) isn't set for the POST case. Could its value be left over from some previous request?

In general, good idea to use local vars wherever possible.